# Will a 3rd Generation Nest thermostat correctly adjust the humidity base on outdoor conditions?

Tags: hvac, humidity, humidifier, nest

If I plug my whole house humidifier into a 3rd generation Nest, is it smart enough to track outdoor temperature and adjust indoor as needed to keep condensation off the inside of the windows?

Comment: Outdoor humidity has no effect on indoor condensation on your windows. Indoor condensation is caused by humid indoor air against the cool glass.

Comment: Sorry, I meant outdoor temperature (I edited the question). In the winter, the humidity must be adjusted manually as the temperature fluctuates. I was hoping that Nest does this automatically as some humidifiers do with outdoor sensors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience Nest's customer support is excellent, they have technicians which seem to be capable of talking homeowners and pros through some fair technical installs.

It appears that this is a [common question](https://www.nest-community.com/s/question/0D51W00004zX9RXSA0/humidifier-control-using-outside-temperature), and that Nest doesn't support this feature yet, but I would call Nest's support line and see if they have any tips.